Get last non-empty text line in StaticLayout
I'm using this StaticLayout.Builder in Android.
  val staticLayout =
        StaticLayout.Builder.obtain(fullText, 0, fullText.length, textPaint, containerWidth).build()

I want to be able to determine the last line with text within the static layout. Ei. if the staticLayout.lineCount = 4, but lines 2 and 4 are line breaks(\n), the last row with text is line 3. Is there a Static layout function I can use to determine this? Or, is there a way to loop through each line of the static layout so I can do it manually?

I don't think that StaticLayout has any method that returns a collection of the lines. There are a few methods by which you can iterate over them manually, though; for example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NCDq6M9DYNH9Qb5U0SFAFfPWuBYBQ23I&usp=drive_fs. I assumed that blank == empty, but you can see where to change it, if that's not quite right.
